# Dealing with incoming data with aliases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping

Bit of a philosophical question this one:

We deal with lots of data that comes in via different channels. 
We're parsing that data to try to make sense of it.

e.g.

```
class Product
attr_accessible :name, :description, :price
has_one :company
end

class Company
attr_accessible :name, :domain, :phone, :email
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :domain

end
```

When the data comes in the company names can vary a bit.

e.g.

```
"Acme Limited"
"Acme Ltd"
"Acme Ltd (Birmingham)"
"Acme Ltd (London)"
```

These are all fundamentally the same company and we'd like to store them as such and automatically assign them (once we've identified an alias).

The variations are down to the way that third parties store the data in their APIs, or on sites which we have no control over.

What's a good way of identifying these aliases and then converting them to the appropriate company as they arrive?

I've thought about adding another class as an association to Company that deals with aliases. 
Alternatively, adding a jsonb column to the table where we can keep an array of aliases, so that if any match we can bring them in.

Just seems like there should be a good solution to this that I'm not finding.

Anyone run into this type of issue and come up with something elegant and beautiful?

Comment: `adding a jsonb column to the table` sounds good enough to me

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce another model, say, `Alias`, that references `Company` and basically has two columns, `company_id` and `alias`. Then one might call `company.aliases` to retrieve a list of aliases.

That way it would be easy/fast to lookup a company when you receive an aliased name from somewhere:

```
Alias.find_by_alias(value_got_from_3rd_party).try(:company)
```

Obviously, there should be a record with real name in `aliases` table as well for the lookup to work smoothly.